# Symfony HWI OAuth login error behind a proxy

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, facebook-login, hwioauthbundle

I am using Symfony2 with HWIOAuth Bundle to login with Facebook Google and twitter. When network connection is behind a proxy login gives following error

> **[2/2] HttpTransportException: Error while sending HTTP request**
>  in
>   vendor\hwi\oauth-bundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\AbstractResourceOwner.php
>   at line 258
>
> **[1/2] RequestException: Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds**
>  in
>   vendor\kriswallsmith\buzz\lib\Buzz\Client\Curl.php at line 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HWIOAuthBundle depends on [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz) which uses php cURL to send requests. So you need to set proxy for cURL. Since symfony framework we can do it without getting our hands dirty. It is as easy as adding a new line to `app/config/config.yml` as follows.

```
# app/config/config.yml 
hwi_oauth:
     http_client:
         proxy: "example.com:8080"   # String with proxy configuration for cURL connections, ignored by default.
                                     # "" -> don't set proxy and will use proxy system
                                     # "example.com:8080" -> set custom proxy
                                     # ":" -> disable proxy usage, ignoring also proxy system and ENVIRONMENT variables
```

[configuring_the_http_client.md](https://github.com/webkod3r/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/internals/configuring_the_http_client.md)

Comment: I have set this command Do I need to change the example.com:8080, still getting the same error

Comment: @HemantsHarma Do you access internet via proxy? Have you set proxy for system? Then example.com should be replaced by your proxy host and 8080 should be replaced by proxy port. If you don't use any proxy to access internet, set `proxy: ":"` Please read comment lines in above example.